# Make a Preference in DefaultSharedPreferances Enabled and Selectable

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an item in DefaultSharedPreferences enabled.

in the preferences.xml I changed the value to `android:enabled="false"`

Now I'm trying to create a piece of code that will make this preference enabled when a checkbox elsewhere in defaultsharedpreferences is checked.

My XML file:

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkboxinternet"
        android:title="Checkbox Preference"
        android:summary="Check it on, check it off"
    />
```

So when this checkbox is checked

```
SharedPreferences ingevuldesysteeminstellingen = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   


    if (true == ingevuldesysteeminstellingen.getBoolean( "checkboxinternet", false )) {
        Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "checkboxinternet", false);
        editor.commit();
    } else { }
```

is this even possible, trying to change the values Enabled and selectable, been looking into this for a few days now, and starting to believe it isn't even possible.

**UPDATE**

So far i got the following part working, and the moment a checkbox get pressed i can get it to execute something. But still i cannot get it to work to make a list or a other checkbox enabled or slectable.

My piece of code so far

```
ingevuldesysteeminstellingen = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences ingevuldesysteeminstellingen,String key) 
        {

            if (key.equals( "checkboxautomaticrefresh")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Checkbox automatic refresh werd uitgelezen");
                //refreshtijdenable();
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }
    };      
    ingevuldesysteeminstellingen.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

So what would be next for me to get te get a list or a checkbox enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
    //Retrieve the other checkbox
    CheckBoxPreference otherCheckboxPref = 
    (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("othercheckboxpreff");

    //Set a listener to the checkbox
    otherCheckboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {  

       public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
           //Retrieve the 'checkboxinternet'
           CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkboxinternet");   
           //If it's checked, set the 'checkboxinternet' Enabled property to true
           if (newValue.toString().equals("true"))
           {  
                checkboxPref.Enabled = true;
           } 
           //Else , set it to false
           else 
           {  
                checkboxPref.Enabled = false;
           }
           return true;
        }
     });
```

Comment: Somehow I can't get to enable something in the defaultsharedpreferences with this one. .findPreference() doesn't seems to work at all for defaultsharedpreferences.

Comment: The Moment this line gets executed: CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkboxinternet");  The Whole prgram crashes, any ideas anyone.

Comment: What exception comes up when it crashes?